# Facebook PHP SDK for login is re generating new code everytime

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

First don't mark it as duplicate because this is new issue came, there was no issue before for this, on server in error file it give this to me "CSRF state token does not match one provided." AND I TRIED ALL SOLUTIONS FROM THIS PLATFORM and also did replaced getCode function in base_facebook.php file as was mentioned in one of the solution.

And with that solution that started working perfectly but from yesterday it is again giving same error and not working, when I click on continue with facebook it keeps generating new auth call with new code.

Please help with that, here is the live test link to it: http://eliteware.co/92/login/

Click on continue with facebook and you will get it.

As I am troubleshooting the code, this line `$facebook->getUser()` always returns zero in php code.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and include relevant code in the question.

Comment: Also, just stating something like _“AND I TRIED ALL SOLUTIONS FROM THIS PLATFORM”_ doesn’t help one bit. We don’t know if you _found_ the right things to begin with, we don’t know if you managed to do something wrong while trying to fix the problem this way, etc. So give us a proper problem description, including what debugging steps you have undertaken so far, and what possible fixes you tried and with what results.

Comment: Sorry guys I am new to it totally. As I am troubleshooting the code, this line '$facebook->getUser()' always returns zero in php code.

Comment: Getting exact same issue...

Comment: Did you manage to solve it somehow? It just literally stopped working over-night for me.